# What is the best fish for the pond?

Tags: stardew-valley

What factors should I consider when stocking the Fish Ponds added in 1.4? Is there a particular fish species that is super useful for recipes or just worth a lot of money I should prioritize?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fish Ponds can be used for two purposes: multiplying fish or other water dwellers, and harvesting roe or other products.

These fish that seem to be particularly useful:

#### Carp

With a value of only 30g, carps are perfect to turn into sashimi for a quick refill of energy.

#### Sturgeon

Sturgeon roe becomes caviar when processed in a preserves jar, which sells for 500g each and benefits from the Artisan profession. Not bad for a constant, passive source of income.

#### Lava Eel

As the most expensive fish that can be placed in fish ponds, lava eels are an obvious choice for anyone just looking for additional money.

#### Eel

Regular eels can be cooked with hot peppers to make the spicy eel dish, which increases both luck and movement speed. Having an easy way to cook many of these is certainly useful, given how luck and movement speed affect almost every aspect of a farmer's life.

#### Lobster

When cooked with milk, lobsters can be turned into lobster bisque, which provides a huge +3 boost to the Fishing skill. Very useful when going after some of the trickier fish to catch.

Comment: Given that the fish reproduce at different rates, are Lava Eels actually the most valuable in terms of g / day? (Admittedly, it has a hefty lead in base price...)

Comment: @RavenDreamer I haven't figured out how quickly fish breed yet, but one thing I've noticed is that lava eels sometimes produce gold ore instead of roe. I'm not sure whether this is unique to lava eels, or if it has a chance of happening with any fish, but non-roe drops might increase a pond's value as well.

Comment: After more research, since Roe price is based on fish base price, Lava Eel roe _is_ better, even if the fish themselves spawn slower.

Comment: Lava eels vs sturgeon (1064 vs 700 for artisan prices of end products) strictly for money is pretty darn close: sturgeons are more likely to produce additional roe in a given day, it's not by much (~8%). Lava eels also produce several other things (like magma geodes and gold ore) occasionally that will block that delicious roe. Either way it's very easy money: swing by once a day and drop whatever you find in a preserving jar. Aged roe also takes 1/3rd less time in the jar, so you'll need fewer jars if farming as scale. It is worth mention it takes a long while to get your pond fully upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

As of patch 1.5, three new fishe types were introduced on Ginger Island, each one with island-related items that are very useful to obtain from a fish pond.

- Lionfish can give you Tiger Slime Eggs (2% per day with 9 population) to hatch. The tiger slime can then be [bred with other slimes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhBt_6ldvLc) for a greater chance of pure white slimes which drop diamonds when killed.
- Blue Discus can give Golden Coconuts (5% per day with 9 population) to break for island goodies. They also give bananas (5 ~15% with 4 population) and can get you the Gorilla G-walnuts faster than waiting for a banana sapling to grow.
- Stingrays can give Magma Caps (2% 4-pop) great sell value and healing, Cinder Shards (8%  7-pop) for the forge, allowing you to skip on farming the volcano dungeon, Dragon Tooth (5% 9-pop) you can trade for banana saplings or make island totems with, and batteries (10% 9-pop).

I strongly recommend several stingray ponds (for forging) and one blue discus for the bananas early on.